# White border at the top

Tags: html, css

Why would this code leave a white strip at the top of the page in google chrome ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>title goes here</title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px">
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">
            <p>&nbsp</p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a tip, when using `padding` or `margin`, if all 4 values are the same, just specify it once, like so: `padding: 0px`

Comment: yeah initially I was doing that, but just to extra sure I tried this and pasted the code : )

Comment: you should put the background color on the form or the body tag.

Comment: I think you can [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) your css.

Comment: Give us a jsfiddle to see if you can reproduce it.

Comment: @DavidNguyen how is that going to help?  create an HTML page with the code and look at it in Chrome.  a JSFiddle won't recreate the issue well.

Comment: Try searching for reset css. Google and add it to the top of your css code. it should reset your browser's default css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The p-tag has a margin that affects its parents.

Add `overflow: auto;` to the div with the background. That prevents margins from [collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: great job! a very few people understand this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks this is of great help!

Answer (score 1):

Give `margin:0; padding:0;` to the `<p>` inside of DIV.

Comment: oh applying a 0 padding and 0 margin to <p> worked fine. Quick question then, does <p> enforce some padding by default ?

Comment: @SaaranshBagga not padding, but margins, yes. So technically just `margin:0` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin:0;` and `padding=0;` to the `html`element as well.

Also, this is a bit far-fetched, but I experienced a similar problem with php files where a utf-8 encoded one **with** BOM would create an empty line before everything else.

Answer (score 0):

The white line is coming from the white space left behind by the line break created by the p tag. Just remove the p tag and it will be gone.

```
    <div style="background-color: blue;">
           &nbsp
    </div>
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer. this doesn't tell anyone very much

Comment: I accidentally hit submit before typing up the explanation. Sorry about that.

Comment: this actually changes the content of the page though